# setTimeout for each instance of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object (this is only part of it, obviously...):

```
function room() {
    this.data = {
        sender_name: '',
        room_id: 0
    }
    this.create = function (sender_name) {
        // (code to set this.data)
        this.removeTimer();
    }
    this.removeTimer = function() {
        var t = this;
        console.log(t.data.sender_name) // log #1

        $.tGet('roomInfo', {'room_id': this.data.room_id}, function(edata) {
            console.log(t.data.sender_name) // log #2
            if(edata.exists == 'false') {
                // remove room code...
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    t.removeTimer();
                }, 1000)
            }
        })
    };
}
```

and I create its instances from DB like this:

```
$.tGet('getRooms', {'user_id': mUser}, function(edata) {
    var i = 0, n;
    for(i = 0; i<edata.length; i++) {
        n = new room();
        n.create(edata[i].sender_name);
    }
})
```

Now, the problem is that what console prints is only the last room created. I don't know what's going on...

The first time this code runs, log #1 is completely correct. However, log #2 is already problematic because it gives me only the last room in the DB (or in the loop...) and, of course, after the timeout log #1 becomes wrong too.

What's going on? I'm really just a begginer at javascript, so...

---

`tGet` function:

```
$.tGet = function(action, data, callback, error) { 
    $.get('php/ajax.php?action='+action, data, callback, 'json').fail(error); 
}
```

Comment: `$.tGet = function(action, data, callback, error) {
    $.get('php/ajax.php?action='+action, data, callback, 'json').fail(error);
}`
It's just a shorter $.get of jquery...

Comment: You might should edit the question to show that. It will be easier to read formatted right. And future generations will find it easier to follow.

Comment: If `edata` is an array, don't you want `n.create(edata[i].sender_name);`?

Comment: yes, it was another typo, it is fine now... but the problem remains the same...

Comment: @user2240933 Ahh okay. What if you use: `(function (i) { n.create(edata[i].sender_name); })(i);` ?

Comment: (I meant to replace your `n.create(edata[i].sender_name);` line with that)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.removeTimer = function() {
    console.log(this.data.sender_name) // log #1

    $.tGet('roomInfo', {
                'room_id': this.data.room_id,
                'instance' : this
            }, function(edata) {
        console.log(this.instance.data.sender_name) // log #2
        if(edata.exists == 'false') {
            // remove room code...
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                instance.removeTimer();
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're creating multiple room instances with the same room id . Should the create line read `n.create(edata[i].room_id)`